# R Преобразование даты формата "2020-01-12" в "2020-01"

Tags: r

У меня есть dataframe df, в которо в колонке m_date лежат даты в формате as. Date "2020-01-12" (y. m. d) . Мне необходимо достать из неё месяц и год "2020-01", чтобы когда я буду производить арифметеческие действия с месяцами, то R меня понимал.

К примеру

```
p<- c( 24)
df$m_date <- df$m_date - p #хочу вычесть год

#Пробовала писать
df$m_date <- as. Date(df$m_date, "%m. %Y") 
#или использовать as. month
```

Желаемого результата это не дало. Я получаю ошибки или na.

Comment: [выбирайте подходящий вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14169620/4827341)

Answer (score 0):

Привест даты к нужному формату можно с помощью функции `strftime` или `format`:

```r
strftime(Sys.Date(), "%m.%Y")
# [1] "02.2020"
```